# How can i replace array[2] (for example) component with the last component of an array of unkown size

Tags: c, arrays, replace, components

I tried to do with a variable like temp but it didnt work.
The points is that i want to pass the value of a component of an `array(fail[f])` to another `array(pass[p])` and fill that blank space with the last component of the same `array(fail[f])` so i can print it in the end.

I tried with an example of grades: 2,4,3,5,6 and in the end it printed correctly for the first two averages, corectly for the final average of those who passed (because I did `pass[*p]=5` as i knew from the exercise that the grades 4 will turn 5 and then passed it on the array `pass[*p]` whose size will enlarge max size 10).

The point is that in the end it printed the final average of the students who failed incorectlly because i was decreasing its size and printing him. That cause the digit -1 to appear as I had previously filled both arrays with -1.

To sum up I need somehow to remove each component `fail[i]=4` from this array and move it to the end of array `pass[i]` as it is now equal to 5.

enter code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
float average(int array[],int size);
int condition(int pass[],int *p,int fail[],int *f,int *fcounter,int *pcounter);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, pass[10],fail[10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        pass[i]=-1;
        fail[i]=-1;
    }

    int end=0;  `flag in case user wants to end`
    int p=0,f=0,g=0; `g=counter for grades`
    int grade;

    do{
        do{
            printf("Enter grade (-1 if you want to end)\n");
            scanf("%d",&grade);
            if(grade==-1){
                end=1;
            }   
            else if(grade<0 || grade>10){
                printf("Wrong input , grade must be between 0 and 10\n");
            }       
        }while((grade<0 || grade>10) && end==0);

        if(grade>=5){
            pass[p]=grade;
            p=p+1;
        }
        else if(grade>=0 && grade<5){
            fail[f]=grade;
            f=f+1;
        }
        g=g+1;
    }while(g<10 && end==0);

    float avg;

    avg=average(pass,p);
    printf("The average of the students who passed is:%f\n",avg);

    avg=average(fail,f);
    printf("The average of the students who failed is:%f\n",avg);

    int fcounter,pcounter;

    fcounter=f;
    pcounter=p;
    int esc=0;

    while(fcounter>pcounter){
        esc=condition(pass,&p,fail,&f,&fcounter,&pcounter);
        if(esc==1){
            pcounter=pcounter+999;  /*so it gets out of the loop*/

    }

    avg=average(pass,p);
    printf("The final average of the students who passed is:%f\n",avg);

    avg=average(fail,f);
    printf("The final  average of the students who failed is:%f\n",avg);

    printf("The grades of the students who passed are:");
    for(i=0;i<p;i++){       
        printf("%d\t",pass[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The grades of the students who failed are:");
    for(i=0;i<f;i++){   
        printf("%d\t",fail[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
float average(int array[],int size){
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    float avrg;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        sum=sum+array[i];
    }
    avrg=(float)sum/size;
    return avrg;
}

int condition(int pass[],int *p,int fail[],int *f,int *fcounter,int *pcounter){
    int i;
    int esc=0;
    int esc_counter=0;

    for(i=0;i<*f;i++){
        if(fail[i]==4){
             fail[i]=fail[*f];   /*the problem is somewhere in these 6 lines i think*/
             pass[*p]=5;          /*i also tried to move element fail[i] to the last place of array 
                                    pass[*p] but still it didnt work and instead i did pass[*p]=5 
                                     cause i knew the outcome is always 5(it is asked on the 
                                      excersise*/
             *f=*f-1;
             *p=*p+1;
             *fcounter=*fcounter-1;
             *pcounter=*pcounter+1; 
            }
        else if(fail[i]!=4){
            esc_counter=esc_counter+1;

        }           
    }
    if(esc_counter=*f){ 
         esc=1;
    }
    return esc;
}
```

Comment: Improved markdown